# relation between the degree of each vertex and the total number of edges in 3-uniform hypergraph?

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a 3-uniform hypergraph with $n$ vertices. Is there any relation between the degree of each vertex and the total number of edges?
For example, when we have a 2-uniform hypergraph (graph) we have $\Sigma_{i=1}^{n}deg(v_i) = 2E.$ 
Is there any such a relation for 3-uniform hypergraph ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's just $\sum \deg(v_i)=3E$ for the same reason: each edge contributes to the degrees of the three vertices in it, so each edge is counted three times in the sum.